# Http links changed to https when published

Tags: http

I have a VS project that has http links and a few https links to other domains. The site is hosted by GoDaddy. Once i publish the files, the formatting is totally off. it appears , based on Chrome’s console, all of my http links (css and js files) are making a call to https. the source document has http. i can not figure out what is making this happen.

in the source it says <link href=“../asset…
it works in debug but once published, in the console the same call is “<link href=https://…”

Comment: Are you uploading plain HTML? Either your host is automatically rewriting your HTML or something in your source so try to eliminate one.

Comment: they are aspx pages. i am using filezilla to transfer.

Comment: Then I would assume your ASP code is doing this. It's important to tag your question correctly and share code.

Comment: I have been creating web pages for a very long time. I have never seen this. Nowhere in the code does this get changed. Showing code in this instance would not help. It is a simple http link that gets converted to https. No code would have changed that from a link. I have multiple sites with GoDaddy and this hasn't happened to any of those.

Comment: What exactly is your point with the last comment?

Comment: just that there is no code that changes a link. it got to be either iis in godaddy or a setting i may have made in the config file, that i don’t see. i have never seen this before so  i was hoping someone could clue me into correcting the issue.

Comment: Do you have a test environment or run code in a dev environment? If so, does the issue appear there? If no, it would be good to have things running in a dev environment. If you have a dev environment and it *doesnt* happen there, can you look at configuration difference? If there's nothing relevant, then it might be godaddy. Asking a support question may be a good option in that case. Try to isolate your issue so at least you know if it's your application or your host.

Comment: Thanks Evert. I’ll look to set up a dev environment. i’ll keep digging.